# jQuery: How do I remove surrounding div tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this line...

```
<div class="textwidget">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

I'd like to get rid of the surrounding div tags with jQuery so the output looks like this:

`lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('.textwidget').replaceWith($('.textwidget').text());
```

Should do it.

Comment: [This will fail if the text happens to contain inline elements](http://jsfiddle.net/7BuGE/).

Answer (score 12):

```
$('.textwidget').contents().unwrap();
```

should work

Comment: I think this is the cleanest answer, and it properly handles content that includes embedded elements.

Answer (score 3):

This will select the text and removes the div tag around it.

```
$('.textwidget').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3
}).unwrap();
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/7SX5u/1/

Comment: where to add these code in wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

`$('.textwidget').replaceWith($('.textwidget').html());`